# Comment function with MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a comment function for every post that comes on website. Brief view :

- Every *post* has an *id*, when posted.
- When the pages loads, MySQL query checks that is there is a table for comment box or not, if not then it creates one.
- in the end of every comment table name, it has the *post id* for ex. if id of a post is `9` then the table name for this post will be `feed_comment_9`. (the table for comments is in another database)
- I was able to connect the comment table and post box in the html view
- But, when the `INSERT INTO` query turn came, i couldn't find a good way

My main question : Is there is any way i can connect these 2 database or can do anything that the insert query will go in the same comment table as of the post.

My codes :

```
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    //database change and creating and checking tables 
    $dbc->select_db("feed_update_comment");
$create_comment_table = "CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS feed_comment_" . $row['id'] . "( id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, full_name varchar(40), comment varchar(120), date_time varchar(100), PRIMARY KEY (id))";
$result_create_comment_table = $dbc->query($create_comment_table);
   //creating and checking finishes 



// making the comments box 
    $dbc->select_db("feed_update_comment");
     $select_comment_table = "SELECT * FROM feed_comment_" . $row['id'] . " ORDER BY id";
$result_query_select_comment_table = $dbc->query($select_comment_table );
if(!$result_query_select_comment_table) {
    $result_select_comment_table = array("full_name" => "", "comment"=> "No comments yet.");

}
$id_result_comment = '<script type="text/javascript">var DivId = $(this).parent(".feed_box_id").attr("id");</script>';
echo '<div id="feed_comment_box_' . $row['id'] . '"' . 'class="feed_comment_box_cl"><div id="add_comment_id" class="add_comment_cl">
<form class="comment_form" method="post" action="' .$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']  . '">
<input name="comment_full_name" type="text" class="input_comment_full_name" required>  </input> 
<textarea required name="input_comment_text" type="text" class="input_comment_text" ></textarea><input class="submit_input" name="comment_submit" type="submit"></input> <br>
 </form>' . $id_result_comment .' 
</div><br>
<div class="comment_box_cl">';      
while ($result_select_comment_table = $result_query_select_comment_table->fetch_assoc()) {
echo '<table tabindex="0" class="comment_box"><tr> <td class="comment_text">' . $result_select_comment_table["comment"] . '</td></tr><br>' . 
'<tr> <td class="comment_full_name">' .  $result_select_comment_table["full_name"]. '</td></tr><br>' . 
'<tr><td class="date_time_comment">' . $result_select_comment_table["date_time"] . '</td></tr><br>'
. '</table>';
}
    echo '</div></div>';    
    echo '</div>';          

    //making of comment box finishes


 //insert query (MAIN POINT)
  if ( isset($_POST["comment_submit"]) ) {
        $commenter_name = ($_POST["comment_full_name"]);
    $commenter_comment = ($_POST["input_comment_text"]);
        if (!empty($commenter_name) || !empty($commenter_comment)) {
            $dbc->select_db("feed_update_comment");
            $result_comment_submit = "INSERT INTO feed_comment_" . " (full_name,comment,date_time)" .  " VALUES('$commenter_name','$commenter_comment',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%h:%i %p,  %W %M %e'))";
            $add_comment_submit = $dbc->query($result_comment_submit)
            or die ("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('not working!');</script>");

        }

    }
```

extra : There are many of these types look at starting the post, down to it comment box. The problem is there will be dozen of it.

[image: There are many of these types]

Comment: Unless you get lots (and I mean 10.000s) of comments, this is an overkill. Simply have a table `comments` which has the post id as a field (preferrably indexed and/as(?) foreign key).

Comment: in the same database ?, could you just help me by showing it in the answers

Comment: @kingkero hitted exactly on the spot... is there any particular reason you need to create a table for each post comments? if you create a comments table with a foreign key to the post table it solves your problems.

Comment: I agree completely with @kingkero, except I would change 10.000s to millions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know which post a comment belongs to, you can use an input with `type="hidden"` like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="comment_post_id" value="' . $row['id'] . '">
```

and access it like you would any other field via `$_POST['comment_post_id']`.

---

Unless you have lots (and you have to consider the definition for lots depending the dbms you're using) of comments, this is an overkill. You create many tables `feed_comment_X` which contain only few entries.

The basic solution is to have **one** table comments, which could look like this

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
  comment_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  post_id INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES posts (id) [ON..],
  full_name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  comment TEXT NOT NULL,
  date_time DATETIME NOT NULL
);
```

You save all comments in this table and don't need to check for existance of and (if necessary) create a new table on each page load.

To get all comments you simply (using parameterized statements)

```
SELECT full_name, comment, date_time FROM comments
  WHERE post_id = :post_id
```

And add a new entry by

```
INSERT INTO comments (post_id, full_name, comment, date_time) VALUES
  (:post_id, :full_name, :comment, :date_time)
```

This allows fast operations if you want to get additional info, eg. the number of comments each post has:

```
SELECT p.id, .., COUNT(c.post_id) AS total_comments FROM posts AS p
  LEFT JOIN comments AS c on c.post_id = p.id
  GROUP BY (p.id)
```

Comment: But, from where will i get the `row[id]` (:post_id) , when i tried in the while loop , it made copy of a comment for all posts. Should i make the `$row` global

Comment: @MihirUjjainwal I hope my update clears things up. This way you need only one check (outside any loop!) if a has been comment posted